# 1798 German handwriting Translation Help

Tags: german-to-english, handwriting, kurrent

[image]My ancestor was a Hessen Hussar in 1798 with General Major Schreiber's Hussar Squadron. I would like help in getting what I outlined in red on the following documents[image] translated.

Comment: The first word you marked seems to be *Leimann*, the second phrase *Husar Leyman*. Leimann and Leyman could be different spellings of the same name.

Comment: Look at https://german.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: TheHessen: As suggested by @PaulFrost, if you think your question was answered by one of the posts below, please consider marking it as "accepted" (via the "checkmark" beside the answer). If you have further queries, feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The first report, dated Lohra, 11 December 1798**, reads:

> Zugleich will Ew: Hhdurchl: melden, daß [/]
> ein Carabinier Becker und ein Hußar [/]
> Leimann, beyde  Gener:l Schreibers [/]
> Escadron <1mo?> an einem Ohrgeschwüre [/]
> kranck, und leztem deßen Pferd [/]
> lahm ist.

"Ew. Hhdurchl." is a form of address used for a ruler and can be broken down to "[Euer](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ew_) [Hochdurchlaucht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serene_Highness#German-speaking_lands)" or "Your (Most) Serene Highness".

I am unsure about the words or signs right before and after "Gener:l Schreibers Escadron". <s>The two vertical strokes may indicate omission and point back to something mentioned above ("said General" / "said squadron"). *Please note that my translation "from said" is conjectural.*</s> The former is, I believe, the word "von" (with a small space left between "vo" and "n").
The (likely) abbreviation after "Escadron" might be a numeral, written in Latin according to tradition. I conjecture "1mo".

Translation:

> I also report to Your Most Serene Highness that a carabinier named Becker and a hussar named Leimann, both from the <1st?> squadron of General Schreiber, fell ill with an abscess to one ear, and the latter's horse is lame.

The last line of **the second report, written on or after 20 January 1799** (it is a record of patrols conducted around Lohra between 16 and 20 January), remarks that

> General-Major Schreiber Escadron ist dem Hussar Leyman sein Pferd welche[s] Lahm geweßen wieder curiert.

Reading the word after "Escadron" as "ist", it translates to:

> [In] the squadron of Major General Schreiber, Husar Leyman's horse, previously lame, has healed.

(Thanks to @SebastianRedl for the pointer on how to interpret "ist ... curiert".)

Note the inconsistent spelling of your ancestor's name in the documents, arguably written by two distinct hands (likely two different secretaries or amanuenses): **Leimann** vs. **Leyman**.

Comment: "ist kuriert" however means "is well again", which makes a lot more sense by itself, since squadrons don't heal horses, lame horses generally heal by themselves after some time. The prefixing of the squadron may just be a shorthand to first refer to a particular squadron that the event concerns. So the full meaning would be "In Major General Schreiber's squadron, Husar Leyman's horse, which was lame, has recovered."

Comment: @SebastianRedl Excellent observation, thanks!

Comment: The shorthand you read _1mo_ could also be read as _po̳_ – basically the same: primo.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough question. I address the first picture:

> Zugleich will so [name?] melden, daß ein Carabinier Beeker und ein Husar Leimann, beijde [] General Schreibers Escadron an einem [] krank und leztem [] Pferd lahm ist.

Translating to: At the same time [name] wants to report, that carabine rifleman Beeker and husar Leimann, both in General Schreibers squadron, are both sick with [] and the latters horse is lame.

Comment: It is not clearly identifiable whether the carabinier's name is *Beeker* or *Becker*. I believe it is *Becker*: 1. There is small dot right over the debatable letter which also occurs over the "c" is *Escadron*. 2. Look a the "c" in *December.