# Deciphering a Hessen Hussar Regiment Patrol Report from 1795

Tags: german-to-english, handwriting, kurrent

Looking to decipher of the two red highlighted sections of the attached report. My ancestor that is mentioned in the report is **Leyman**.
[image]

Comment: Don't ask for *translation* or your question might be closed due to formal reasons. You might ask for *deciphering*, that's agreed to be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Transcription**

> *Patrouillen Rapport*

> Von dem vom Hochlöblichen Hussaren Regiment nach Lohra detachirten Commando vom 25ten bis inclusive den 31ten Octobr 1795.

> < Da>tum < Octo>b: <179>5 // Wer die Patrouille geritten // Stunde: des Abgangs / der Wiederankunft // Was für einen Weg sie genommen, und was für Orthe sie berührt hat. // Ob sie etwas angetroffen, und was sie neues eingebracht hat.

> <den 2>6ten // Gefr: Leyman Hussar Bergman // Mittag 12 / Nach Mitt. 4 // Heimershausen und die Grenze von Züschen // ∅

Interestingly, the row for the 29th of October mentions another "Hussar Leyman". Here is the transcription:

> <den 2>9ten // Gefr: Hahn Hussar Leyman // Morg 8 / Nach Mit 1/2 1 // Balhorn // ∅

Notes:

- The place name I decipher "Lohra" could hypothetically be read as "Lohna", but from [your other post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71184) we know that this regiment was stationed at Lohra, Hessen.
- In the extra row, the expression "1/2 1" stands for "halb eins", or 12:30 (PM).

**Translation**

> *Report of patrols*

> [conducted] by the unit detached to Lohra from the honored/commendable(?) Hussar Regiment from October 25th through 31th, 1795.

> Date in October 1795 // Who rode on patrol // Hour: of departure / of return // What route it took and what places it touched upon // Whether it came across something [worth reporting], and what news it gathered.

> 26th // *Gefreiter* Leyman, hussar Bergman // 12 (noon) / 4 PM / Heimershausen and the border at Züschen // none

And the extra row with the hussar Leyman:

> 29th // *Gefreiter* Hahn, hussar Leyman // 8 AM / 12:30 PM / Balhorn // none

Notes:

- I translated "hochlöblich" as "honored/commendable"; I do not know whether this might be a more specific, technical predicate for military units. (Maybe along the lines of: decorated? veteran? or the like.)
- The row of the 29th mentions a "Hussar Leyman", while the row of the 26th that you marked mentions a "Gefr: Leyman". Assuming rigid ranks and roles in the regiment, these must be two different people sharing the name Leyman. I leave it to you to decide which one is your ancestor.

**EDIT:** As @HalvarF and @PaulFrost have pointed out in the comments, a *Gefreiter* was one rank higher than a simple hussar (in my original answer, I had assumed the opposite). From [your earlier post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71184), we gather that your ancestor Leyman was a *hussar* in late 1798/early 1799. Identifying your ancestor with the *Gefreiter* in this 1795 document would entail his demotion to the lowest rank of *hussar* in the meantime.

Comment: Could the "Gefr." be something else, like "Gn.fr" and just mark the leader of the patrouille (e.g. Gruppenführer, but I don't know it it's that)? "Ziehm" and "Estein"(?) are also mentioned once as Gn.fr. and once as a Hussar. It would also be a bit strange to always mention a Gefreiter (lower rank) before a Hussar.

Comment: @HalvarF: Agree with your sound observations on the strange order of ranks and on the repetition of names. – However, (1) look at the "-e-"s in other words (Weg, geritten, genommen), this I think forces us to read "Gefr."; and (2) compare the [other patrol report from 1799](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71184), where the word is consistently (almost) written out as "Gefreit."; which I assume applies here too. – Even assuming rigid ranks and roles (*private* vs. *hussar*), the repeated names might be due to family kinship among the soldiers, or to mere homonimy.

Comment: Thanks for catching the Leyman on the 29th.  Don't know how I missed that.  I am pretty sure it is the same Leyman.  I have unit logs for each year from 1787-1806 and he is the only one. In other documents they have  spelled his name in various forms (Leimann, Leymann, Leiman, Leyman, and Ley)

Comment: @marquinho: Ah, I didn't see the other question -- that's very convincing of course. I also found out that my idea of the ranks was wrong: Hussar was the lower and Gefreiter was the higher rank.

Comment: @HalvarF: Oh, that sounds great! Do you have a source that we could quote re: rank hierarchy?

Comment: @marquinho: not for that time and place, and not a citeable one. But it seems to be a very basic fact (that I just didn't know). The Husar was the simple soldier rank, the Gefreiter was one above. Before that they were "Rekrut". See e.g. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dienstgrade_des_Deutschen_Heeres_(Deutsches_Kaiserreich)
Today it's different since e.g. in the Bundeswehr, basically everyone becomes a "Gefreiter" already after 6 months, so the simple soldier ranks like "Schütze", "Flieger", "Matrose" etc. are now devalued to what was the Rekrut back then.

Comment: @marquinho Look at p.77 of http://www.vhghessen.de/inhalt/dig_bib/Beitraege_zur_hessischen_Landesgeschichte/01_Boehme_Die%20Wehrverfassung%20in%20Hessen-Kassel.pdf. A "Hussar" was a member of a cavalry regiment (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hussar) and I think that HalvarF is right when he states that if "Hussar" is used as a military rank, it is the lowest one, i.e. a *Gemeiner*.