# Deciphering a Hessen Hussar Regiment Patrol Report Header from 1791

Tags: german-to-english, handwriting, kurrent

Please help decipher the heading of the Patrol Report.

[image]

Comment: Another important recommendation when asking for help: *Please show us your previous research* / *take the time to try to help yourself* (as per [site rules](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)). Posts that come across as a mere request ("please do X for me") are generally frowned upon and closed.

Comment: In the case of this question (and any similar queries in the future), you should try to transcribe as much as you can yourself. Your previous [posts](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71260) should provide a good starting point. Then you can point to the parts for which you still need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Patrouillen Rapport*

> Von der(!) in der Grafschaft Hanau und zwar in Altenmittlau D< eta>chirten Commando des hochl: Hussaren Regiments vom 23ten Nvbr bis den 20 Dcbr 1791.

I marked "Von der" since I would have expected "Von dem", as it must agree with "Commando" ("das Commando" according to [Adelung's dictionary](https://lexika.digitale-sammlungen.de/adelung/lemma/bsb00009131_5_0_429)). The word I transcribed as "Grafschaft" could also read "Graffschaft", which is but an alternate spelling of the same. "Detachirt" is partially unreadable here, but your [other](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71184/) [posts](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/71260/) make it sufficiently clear. "hochl:" abbreviates "hochlöblichen".

**Translation**:

> *Report of patrols*

> [conducted] by the unit detached from the honored Hussar Regiment to the County of Hanau, precisely to Altenmittau, from November 23th through December 20th, 1791.

The [Grafschaft Hanau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafschaft_Hanau#Das_Erbe) (County of Hanau) was by this time included in the [Landgraviate of Hesse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landgrafschaft_Hessen-Kassel).

Comment: Möglicherweise steht "Commando" für "Commando-Compagnie" und daher das weibl. Geschlecht.

Comment: @Roland: Danke, das ist eine mögliche Deutung. Ich bin von Homogenität und Formelhaftigkeit ausgegangen; in beiden anderen bisher vorliegenden Dokumenten dieser Art heißt es "Vom ... detachirten Commando".

Comment: Das mag im Laufe der Jahre (1791, 1795, 1798) geändert worden sein. Ich frage mich auch, wie fixiert das Geschlecht dieses Lehnwortes Ende des 18 Jhd. war.